# adding plus symbol at the end of each line wrapping

Tags: json, xml, xslt

i want to add the plus symbol at the end of the line wrapping inside the single sentence(single para). Is it possible to do like this?

My Input xml file is:

```
<response>
    <p>Developing additional problems with your health that are related to your diabetes is by no means a foregone conclusion. There is much you can do to lower your risk.  By accepting your diabetes diagnosis and educating yourself about the complications that can occur and how to prevent them, you have already taken an important first step.</p>
   </response>
```

I used XSL as

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0">
       <xsl:template match="response">
               "response": "<xsl:apply-templates/>"
           </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output needs to be in word wrap mode with + symbol:

```
   "response": "Developing additional problems with your health that are related to" + 
   "your diabetes is by no means a foregone conclusion. There is much you can do to" +
   "lower your risk.  By accepting your diabetes diagnosis and educating yourself" +
    "about the complications that can occur and how to prevent them, you have" + 
"already taken an important first step."
```

Is this possible to do? If it is, please help me on this. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample using XSLT 2.0 and a function using `xsl:analyze-string` with a regular expression to break up a string into chunks of a certain limit (defined as an integer parameter):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf" version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer" select="80"/>

    <xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string" select="concat('((.{1,', $length, '})( |$))')"/>

    <xsl:param name="sep" as="xs:string" select="' + &#10;'"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:break" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="result">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex="{$pattern}">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', regex-group(2), '&quot;')"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() ne last()">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="response">
        "response": <xsl:sequence select="mf:break(normalize-space())"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transforms your sample input into the output

```
        "response": "Developing additional problems with your health that are related to your" + 
"diabetes is by no means a foregone conclusion. There is much you can do to lower" + 
"your risk. By accepting your diabetes diagnosis and educating yourself about the" + 
"complications that can occur and how to prevent them, you have already taken an" + 
"important first step.
```

I think the function can be shortened to

```
<xsl:function name="mf:break" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:value-of separator="{$sep}">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex="{$pattern}">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:sequence select="concat('&quot;', regex-group(2), '&quot;')"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:value-of>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: "response": "Developing additional problems with your health that are related to your" + 
"diabetes is by no means a foregone conclusion. There is much you can do to lower" + 
"your risk. By accepting your diabetes diagnosis and educating yourself about the" + 
"complications that can occur and how to prevent them, you have already taken an" + 
"important first step.

Comment: in place of double quote i want single quote how i can get.